# Check if xdebug is working

Tags: php, xdebug

Without installing a texteditor or an IDE, is it possible to test if xdebug is working, i.e. if it can debug php code?

The only part xdebug comes up in phpinfo() is the following:

> Additional .ini files parsed  /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysql.ini,
>   /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo.ini,
>   /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
>   /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini

It is not mentioned in the phpinfo() anywhere else.

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` report it as a loaded extension? Is that what you mean by "working"?

Comment: If it is showing on on your phpinfo() you could try to telnet on Xdebugs port (which is 9000 by default)

Comment: @Wiseguy,  I've updated the question.  Does that mean it's loaded/working properly?

Comment: @tix3, I've updated the question. Does that mean it's loaded/working properly?

Comment: If the extension is actually loaded, it should have its own section that lists its configuration directives.

Comment: `xdebug.default_enable=1` was 0 in php.ini in my case.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Without actually doing some debugging, I guess you can't be *certain* that a debugger is working.

But you can be pretty sure -- I guess one should assume that if some aspects of xDebug are working then it would all be working.

Given that, you can confirm that xDebug is installed and in place by trying the following:

1) `phpinfo()` -- this will show you all the extensions that are loaded, including xDebug. If it is there, then it's a safe bet that it's working.

2) If that isn't good enough for you, you can try using the `var_dump()` function. xDebug modifies the output of `var_dump()` to include additional information. If this is in place, then xDebug is working.

3) xDebug modifies PHP's error output. If your program crashes with xDebug in place, you'll get more information about the failure than with the standard PHP crash output.

4) xDebug also adds a number of helper functions to PHP. You could try any of these to see if it's working. For example, the function `xdebug_get_code_coverage()` should exist and return an array. If it does, then xDebug is installed. If not, it isn't.

Comment: phpinfo() only mentions xdebug in `Additional .ini files parsed`.  Checking the rest of your suggestions now.

Comment: Just tried `xdebug_get_code_coverage()` and I get `Fatal error: Call to undefined function xdebug_get_code_coverage() in /var/www/xdebug.php on line 5`.

Comment: fair enough. That fairly conclusively tells you that xdebug is not installed correctly.

Comment: Just an FYI if that's the case then you should open up your `/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini` file, which is the one mentioned in additional .ini files parsed, and uncomment all the lines in it.

`zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp`

Comment: @TonyMorello I think that helped me, because my php.ini was setup correctly with the full path, but in Debian there is also a `/mods-available` directory and that xdebug.ini setting was in conflict (I think) with my php.ini setting.

Comment: I am basically using this:
`php -r "xdebug_get_code_coverage();"`

Comment: `var_dump()` format is changed only if xdebug.mode `develop` is enabled.

Answer (score 82):

Run

```
php -m -c
```

in your terminal, and then look for `[Zend Modules]`. It should be somewhere there if it is loaded!

**NB**

If you're using Ubuntu, it may not show up here because you need to add the `xdebug` settings from `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` into `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.

### My Xdebug settings:

#### For Xdebug 3 <sup>(and above)</sup>

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=localhost
;# The default is 9003
xdebug.client_port=9000
```

#### For Xdebug 2.9 <sup>(or below)</sup>

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Comment: `php --version` also lists with Xdebug if its loaded

Comment: @mfink  `php --version` doesn't work for me. Just after starting my machine, after Apache is started and working, `php --version` shows Xdebug, but `phpinfo()` does not show an xdebug section. And PHP script execution does not stop at breakpoints. After I run `service apache2 restart`, `phpinfo()` shows the xdebug section and debugging works. So, for some reason, xdebug is not being loaded when Apache starts during machine boot-up. So for now I'm having to restart Apache after every boot.

Answer (score 49):

Try as following, will return `xDebug does exists.` or `xDebug doesn't exists.`:

```
<?=sprintf('xDebug does%s exists.', extension_loaded('xdebug') ? '' : "n't");
```

On CLI:

```
php -r "printf('xDebug does%s exists.' . PHP_EOL, 
extension_loaded('xdebug') ? '' : 'n\'t');"
```

Answer (score 29):

After a bitter almost 24 hours long run trying to make xdebug to work with Netbeans 8.0.2, I have found a solution that, I hope, will work for all Ubuntu and Ubuntu related stacks.

**Problem number 1: PHP and xdebug versions must be compatible**

Sometimes, if you're running a Linux setup and apt-get to install xdebug, it won't get you the proper xdebug version. In my case, I had the latest php version but an old xdebug version. That must be due to my current Xubuntu version. Software versions are dependent on repositories, which are dependent on the OS version you are running.

Solution: PHP has a neat extension manager called PECL. Follow the instructions given [here](http://www.mkfoster.com/2009/01/04/how-to-install-a-php-pecl-extensionmodule-on-ubuntu/) to have it up and running. 
First, as pointed out by a member at the comments, you should install PHP's developer package in order to get PECL to work:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

Then, using PECL, you'll be able to install the latest stable version of xdebug:

```
sudo pecl install php5-xdebug
```

Once you do it, the proper version of xdebug will be installed but not ready to use. After that, you'll need to enable it. I've seen many suggestions on how to do it, but the fact of the matter is that PHP needs some modules to be enabled both to the client and the server, in this case Apache. It seems that the best practice here is to use the built in method of enabling modules, called php5enmod. Usage is described [here](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/managing-php-5-4-extensions-on-ubuntu).

**Problem number 2: Enable the module correctly**

First, you'll need to go inside the /etc/php5 folder. In there, you'll find 3 folders, apache2, cli, and mods_available. The mods_available folder contains text files with instructions to activate a given module. The name convention is [module].ini. Take a look inside a few of them, see how they are set up.

Now you'll have to create your ini file inside mods_available folder. Create a file named xdebug.ini, and inside the file, paste this:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Make sure that the directive **[xdebug]** is present, exactly like the example above. It is imperative for the module to work. In fact, just copy and paste the whole code, you'll be a happier person that way. :D

Note: the zend_extension path is very important. On this example it is pointing o the current version of the PHP engine, but you should first go to /usr/lib/php5 and make sure the folder that is named with numbers is the correct one. Adjust the name to whatever you see there, and while you're at it, check inside the folder to make sure the xdebug.so is really there. It should be, if you did everything right.

Now, with your xdebug.ini created, it's time to enable the module. To do that, open a console and type:

```
php5enmod xdebug
```

If everything went right, PHP created two links to this file, one inside /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d and other inside /etc/php5/cli/conf.d

Restart your Apache server and type this on the console:

```
php -v
```

You should get something like this:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2015 19:17:11) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.3.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

Which means the PHP client did read your xdebug.ini file and loaded the xdebug.so module. So far so good.

Now create a phpinfo script somewhere on your web server, and run it. This is what you should see, if everything went wright:

[image]

If you see this, Apache also loaded the module, and you are probably ready to go. Now let's see if Netbeans will debug correctly. Create a very simple script, add some variables, give them values, and set a break point on them. Now hit CTRL+F5, click on "step in" on your debugger panel, and see if you get something like this:

[image: xdebug in action]

Remember to check Netbeans configuration for debugging, under tools/options/php. It should look something like this:

[image: Debugging configurations on Netbeans]

I hope this sheds some light on this rather obscure, confusing problem.

Best wishes!

Comment: worked for me, this answer should be on xdebug or netbeans site probably

Comment: I had to install PHP's developer package in order to get PECL to work: 
`sudo apt-get install php5-dev`.

Comment: Also, `php5enmod` doesn't create any links in ini files, it works neatly without.

Comment: One more thing: The `[xdebug]` directive in the ini file is crucial to get it to work. I was confused by the fact that, in the original ini file, the `[xdebug]` was missing, but for me it didn't work without.

Comment: Hello!
You are right about installing PHP's developer package, I'll update the post to accordingly. Not sure about your comment on the php5enmod thou. It creates the links on the folders I've specified. And yes, the [xdebug] directive is imperative, I'll update the post to reflect that as well.

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I'm failed trying to install xdebug via pecl with message `parsePackageName(): "xdebug" is neither a valid version nor a valid state in "php5-xdebug"
invalid package name/package file "php5-xdebug"
install failed` Is it becaus of MacOS I have?

Answer (score 14):

Just to extend [KsaR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5304702/ksar)s answer and provide a possibility to check xdebug from command line:

> ```
> php -r "echo (extension_loaded('xdebug') ? '' : 'non '), 'exists';"
> ```

Answer (score 12):

Starting with xdebug 3 you can use the following command line :

```
php -r "xdebug_info();"
```

And it will display useful information about your xdebug installation.

Answer (score 6):

you can run this small `php` code

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Copy the whole output page,
paste it in this [link](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php). Then analyze. It will show if Xdebug is installed or not. And it will give instructions to complete the installation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **Eclipse** then please note that while running on XDebug mode the magic constant __FILE__ will always be evaluated to:

```
xdebug://debug-eval
```

So the following check will return **true** if your session is under XDebug:

```
$is_xdebug = false !== strpos(__FILE__,'xdebug'); // true while on XDebug
```

Answer (score 2):

in your question you mentioned that your phpinfo was stating that apache was loading xdebug's configuration in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini
In many of the instructions online you may note that they ask you to put xdebug config in php.ini (and that is what I did) HOWEVER, if the configuration is set to /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini, then you should remove the [XDebug] configuration settings from /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and put it in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini INSTEAD.  Once I removed from /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and put in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini instead, and restarted apache, it worked!!

Therefore, in your /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini, put the following:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/home/paul/tmp"

xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp";
xdebug.idekey="phpstorm_xdebug"
```

then remove this from the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini if you put it there as well.

Then  do:

sudo service apache2 restart

Then it should work!!!

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that with [xDebug 3](https://xdebug.org/download#releases) the configuration options [have changed](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide). The PhpStorm Manual: [Configure xDebug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.1/configuring-xdebug.html) also explains it well (it comes with a validator script, which is being uploaded).
After messing around with a PECL version, which could not be configured, the answer was:

```
su
dnf remove php-xdebug
dnf install php-devel

cd /usr/src
wget https://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-3.0.4.tgz
tar -xvzf xdebug-3.0.4.tgz
cd xdebug-3.0.4/
phpize
./configure --enable-xdebug
make
make install
```

xDebug 3 works with such a config (notice the `[xdebug]` section):

```
; Enable xdebug extension module
zend_extension=xdebug.so

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.client_port=9003
```

Which goes into these two files:

```
nano /etc/php-cli.d/xdebug.ini
nano /etc/php.d/xdebug.ini
```

Then one can permit the network connection and reload the INI:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

And finally:

```
php -r "xdebug_info();"
```

Comment: This is important because on a new install of eclipse I found it had the default xdebug configuration set to use port 9000 instead of 9003. This meant that when a debug configuration was run, eclipse was left "waiting for xdebug response", which of course never arrived, as it was listening on the wrong port.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if xdebug installed or not with this command php -v in terminal

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is a bit old, but xdebug 3 came out and a lot of things have changed.

```
php.exe -r "xdebug_info();"
```

Still works, but the configuration in php.ini is different:

For a [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org) installation (php 8.0.12) I have:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\zend_ext\php_xdebug-3.1.1-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.output_dir="c:/xampp/xdebug"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.log=c:/xampp/xdebug/xdebug.log
xdebug.log_level=7
xdebug.profiler_output_name=%p.%t.cgrind
```

Which also will write a `xdebug.log`  file with the following content:

```
[8028] Log opened at 2021-10-28 09:42:33.878279
[8028] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[8028] [Config] INFO: No shared secret: Activating
[8028] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[8028] [Step Debug] ERR: Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
[8028] Log closed at 2021-10-28 09:42:34.298475
```

For [wampserver](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=english) xdebug is included and active out of the box. Which makes it a bit easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps from this blog: [links](https://5minuteshack.blogspot.com/2022/08/xdebug-phpstorm-and-docker-why-it-not.html)

It help me solve the issue, my mistake is added the debugging folder to exclusive so it return error when i put breakpoint to that folder.