# Why I can't debug this simple PHP script using Aptana and XDebug?

Tags: php, debugging, aptana, xdebug, aptana3

I am pretty new in PHP development and I am finding some problem debugging a simple test application.

I am using Aptana Studio 3 on a Ubuntu environment and I am following this tutorial: http://php.tutorialhorizon.com/how-to-debug-php-in-aptana-studio/

So I have configured the PHP interpreter with the following values:

**Name: Php-int**

**Executable Path: /usr/bin/php5**

**PHP ini file: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini**

**PHP Debugger: XDebug**

And this is my simple php file into my php project that I am trying to debug:

```
<?php
    echo "BEGIN ";
    for( $i = 0 ; $i < 5; $i++ ){
        echo "Hello Aptana Studio";
    }
?>
```

So if I try tu **run** this simple script I correctly obtain the output:

```
BEGIN Hello Aptana StudioHello Aptana StudioHello Aptana StudioHello Aptana StudioHello Aptana Studio
```

Then I add some breakpoint. For example on these 2 lines:

```
echo "BEGIN ";
```

and
    echo "Hello Aptana Studio";

Then I try to debug it (**right click on the previous php file ---> Debug as ---> PHP Script**) but now it still to give me the previous output and it don't stop the execution on the first breakpoint. It executes again from the beginning to the end and doedn't stop the execution at the breakpoints.

Why? What am I missing?

Tnx

Comment: What are you trying to debug?

Comment: the previous simple debug test project that only contains the described simple php file

Comment: Are you sure Xdebug is installed and your PHP is properly configured to use it?

Comment: What have I to do to check if it is installed and correctly configured?

Comment: This answer has some good info on that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046501/check-if-xdebug-is-working Also the installation documentation for xdebug http://xdebug.org/docs/install